# Keep selected option of the drop-down box after submitting the form via PHP

Tags: php, dropdownbox

```
<label for='order-number'>Order Number: </label>
<select name='orderNumber' id='order-number'>
<option></option>
<?php
   // Select all order numbers
   $query_orderNumber = "SELECT orderNumber FROM orders ORDER BY orderNumber ASC";

   // Store them into $order_numbers
   $order_numbers = mysqli_query($connection, $query_orderNumber);

   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($order_numbers)) {
      $num = $row['orderNumber'];
      $selected = (isset($_POST['orderNumber']) && ($_POST['orderNumber']=='$num')) 
                   ? "selected='selected'":'';
      echo "<option value='$num' ". $selected. " >$num</option>";
   }
?>
</select>
```

I created this drop-down list with the data from a database. I want to keep the selected option after submitting the form by PHP. But it doesn't keep the option I selected.

Comment: `$_POST['orderNumber']=='$num')` is to be replaced with `$_POST['orderNumber']=="$num")` or with no quotes to the `$num`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried them, and they work well. But I don't understand why single quotation marks don't work here.

Comment: When you put something inside single quote it is just a string, but when you put a variable without quotes or within double quotes the value in the variable would be used for comparision.

Comment: For better understanding,

`<?php
$num = 250;
echo '$num'; // this would just print as $num
echo $num; // this would print 250
echo "$num"; // this would print 250 as well
?>`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use '$num' like this

```
$selected = (isset($_POST['orderNumber']) && ($_POST['orderNumber']== $num)) ? "selected='selected'":'';
```

Comment: Thanks, it works now. Can I ask why it can work after removing double quotation marks?

Comment: @Dyan Actually you were using single quotes, that means $num value you were comparing order_number with a string value as '$num' and not with the stored value of $num variable. You could have used double quotes also, but not single quotes as it will be treated as string and not as a variable.